# Lib.Web.Mvc with edittype select and multiple true

Tags: c#, jqgrid, lib.web.mvc

After read [this post](http://tpeczek.codeplex.com/discussions/286543) of a custom implementation of DataEvents on Lib.Web.Mvc.
I need to create a column of type ListBox, something like

```
[Required]
[Display(Name = "Actions")]
[JqGridColumnEditable(true, "Actions", "Home", EditType = JqGridColumnEditTypes.Select)]
[JqGridColumnEditOptions.Multiple=true]
public string Actions { get; set; }
```

Can anyone help me or give me a reference. I really do not know how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can subclass `JqGridColumnEditableAttribute` and add `Multiple` property through `HtmlAttributes` collection:

```
public class JqGridColumnMultipleEditableAttribute : JqGridColumnEditableAttribute
{
    public bool Multiple { get; set; }

    protected override IDictionary<string, object> HtmlAttributes
    {
        get
        {
            if (Multiple)
                return new Dictionary<string, object>() { { "multiple", "multiple" } };
            else
                return null;
        }
    }

    public JqGridColumnMultipleEditableAttribute(bool editable)
        : base(editable)
    {
        Multiple = false;
    }

    public JqGridColumnMultipleEditableAttribute(bool editable, string dataUrlRouteName)
        : base(editable, dataUrlRouteName)
    {
        Multiple = false;
    }

    public JqGridColumnMultipleEditableAttribute(bool editable, string dataUrlAction, string dataUrlController) :
        this(editable, dataUrlAction, dataUrlController, null)
    { }

    public JqGridColumnMultipleEditableAttribute(bool editable, string dataUrlAction, string dataUrlController, string dataUrlAreaName)
        : base(editable, dataUrlAction, dataUrlController, dataUrlAreaName)
    {
        Multiple = false;
    }
}
```

You can use attribute created in this way like this:

```
[Required]    
[Display(Name = "Actions")]    
[JqGridColumnMultipleEditable(true, "Actions", "Home", EditType = JqGridColumnEditTypes.Select, Multiple=true)]      
public string Actions { get; set; }
```

This will cause jqGrid to render ListBox (you might need to do some styling to make it look good).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, you really are the best!

Comment: Can we add a new searchableAttribute as well in similar way that obtains data from a datacontext and returns a string. I am trying to populate the JqGridColumnSearchType.Select and need to fill in the value from a dbcontext.mytypes.

Comment: @FarrukhSubhani Please contact me via email or start a thread here: http://tpeczek.codeplex.com/discussions. SO comments are not the best place for discussions ;)

Comment: Appreciate your help. i created a select action method on my controller and used it to populate. Great helper. Code gone in production so happy days.

Comment: @tpeczek, you really are the best